# Navbar deixa de funcionar quando tem um iframe na página

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando o Bootstrap 2.3, eu tenho uma `navbar` que sempre funcionou bem, porém depois que passei a usar um `iframe` em uma página, o meu `navbar` parou de funcionar, ele continua sendo exibido normalmente, porém os links dele deixaram de funcionar, eu clico em um link e não acontece nada, agora se eu removo o `iframe` da página volta a funcionar perfeitamente.

Existe alguma incompatibilidade nesse componente (`navbar`) do Bootstrap quando se usa `iframes`?

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar os códigos da `navbar` e do `iframe`?

Answer (score 2):

Erikson, pelo que sei, não existe incompatibilidade entre Boostrap e o elemento `iframe`.

O que acontece é que o `iframe` quase sempre carrega uma outra página, às vezes até mesmo externamente ao domínio utilizado. Como você não deu exemplo do que e como está fazendo, eu acredito que esteja carregando outra página. E pode acontecer que esta outra página esteja chamando *scripts* e este sim podem estar interferindo na barra de navegação.

Apenas como forme de de testes, eu criei um código no [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) utilizando o [Boostrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2) e adicionei uma navbar cujo código eu copiei do próprio exemplo do site do Boostrap.

Adicionei no meu código um `iframe` e nele eu chamei o site do UOL no atributo `src`.

[**Veja o exemplo completo no JS BIN:**](http://jsbin.com/molegofeda/1/)